# Getting error while setting up a Kafka Producer and consumer using Kafkacat

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

used these commands to set up a kafka server and then build a basic producer consumer model for sending hello from producer to consumer.

```
brew services start zookeeper
brew services start kafka
kcat -P -b localhost:9092 -t topic1 
kcat -C -b localhost:9092 -t topic1 -o beginning
```

Getting this error while running consumer code in separate terminal.

```
ERROR: Topic topic1 error: Broker: Unknown topic or partition
```

Comment: Is the kafka port correct? Have you created `topic1` on the kafka broker running at `localhost:9092`?

Comment: Please show the output of `kcat -L -b localhost:9092`

Comment: there is no output of ```kcat -L -b localhost:9092``` . I am able to connect to this port using telnet

Answer (score 1):

You have not actually produced any messages, so the topic was not created. *kcat -P* reads input from the console and sends it to Kafka, and in this case you are not sending anything.

For instance, these commands:

```
echo "My Message" | kcat -P -b localhost:9092 -c 1 -t some-topic
kcat -C -b localhost:9092 -t some-topic
```

Will generate this output:

```
My Message
% Reached end of topic some-topic [0] at offset 1
```

Comment: I don't get it why it works with echo but it works. I even get error messages if I connect to the wrong port. Without echo it does not send the messages to the kcat consumer.

Comment: kcat -P does not actually produce any messages. It waits for you to write something in the console, and when you hit 'Enter' it will actually produce a message to Kafka. the 'echo' command just pipes a single line of text into kcat -P. You could do the same by running the kcat -P command and then writing 'My Message' and Enter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did indeed use it as you explained. None of the sent messages were received. Idk if they were even sent in the first place. So far I can send them only using echo. Not a big deal since I have setup kafka-ui and many other tools to produce and consume messages. I was just wondering why kcat seems not to send them.